# Can I predict the size of an R object?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

If I know the types of data and number of elements to put into a `list` or `data.frame` is it possible to predict the size of the R object?

i.e. for any `n` (assume replace = T if need be):

```
   obj <- list(some_letters = letters[sample(n)], some_months = month.name[sample(n)], some_nums = 1:n)
```

what would be the formula to predict the size of `obj`?

Comment: This is relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29701721/1412059 I think at best you might be able to estimate an upper boundary for the memory size.