# Problem importing CSV file with multiple date columns (yyyy-mm-dd) - all dates get formatted as strings

Tags: r, csv, date, format

I have a large database as CSV-file with multiple date fields (>30)
All dates appear as yyyy-mm-dd (i.e. 2023-09-13) in the CSV-file.
When importing using read.csv2, all the dates are formatted as strings (chr), I could convert each column manually, but since there are so many dates, I hope to find a smoother way to fix it.

Is there any clever way to make R import these dates correctly as date format in the first place?

`db <- read.csv2("~/Dropbox/data_in.csv", sep=";")`

Comment: I don't believe there's a base R way, but if you use `readr::read_delim2` or `data.table::fread` they tend to be smarter about column classes (as well as much faster on large files).

Comment: You can use `lubridate`  package to convert all column to `datetime` type using `ymd()` function. Another tip is try to open the csv file in excel and check if the date column is really in `date type` or are they  `strings`. An example of your data would be useful for someone to help you.

Comment: Another possibility is to use `readr::parse_dates()` separately on all date columns, like `X[, date_cols] <- lapply(X[date_cols], parse_dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `across` along with selecting helpers from `dplyr` package to change multiple variables:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
dat <- data.frame(
   id = 1:100,
   date1 = rep("2023-09-13", 100),
   date2 = rep("2023-09-13", 100),
   date3 = rep("2023-09-13", 100),
   date4 = rep("2023-09-13", 100),
   date5 = rep("2023-09-13", 100)
)

str(dat)
#> 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  6 variables:
#>  $ id   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ date1: chr  "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date2: chr  "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date3: chr  "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date4: chr  "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date5: chr  "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...

dat |> 
   mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) |> 
   str()
#> 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  6 variables:
#>  $ id   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ date1: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date2: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date3: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date4: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date5: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...

dat |> 
   mutate(across(2:6, as.Date)) |> 
   str()
#> 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  6 variables:
#>  $ id   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ date1: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date2: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date3: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date4: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
#>  $ date5: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There are several other helper functions, see ``dplyr::select`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Greatly appreciated. The following was exactly what I needed: dat |> 
   mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date))

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things when discussing importing `Date`-class columns into R: speed of import, and whether it first reads in as strings before conversion or converts on-the-fly.

The latter might be a factor (with large-ish data) because of R's global string pool, something that has historic importance and can hinder larger data. See [Object size for characters in R - How does R global string pool work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29701721/3358272), https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#character-vectors, and https://github.com/krlmlr/stringpool for much more discussion on it, but the bottom line is that if we can avoid reading many strings into R that we know will not be kept as strings, that's generally better. Should you be concerned about the global string pool if your data is 1000 rows or so? Probably not. Certainly not to the point of compromising comfortable-code and/or other features just for the sake of reducing exposure to it.

I'll attempt a crude measure: `system.time(.)` for "speed of import", and resident set size (RSS) from `ps::ps_memory_info()` before and after the import.

Data setup:

```r
n <- 1e7
write.csv2(data.frame(int=1:n, dat=rep(Sys.Date(),n)), "quux.csv", row.names=FALSE)
file.info("quux.csv")
#               size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime  uid  gid uname grname
# quux.csv 188888909 FALSE  664 2023-09-13 08:01:47 2023-09-13 08:01:47 2023-09-13 08:02:11 1000 1000    r2     r2
```

For each of the import mechanisms, I run similar code, replacing `read.csv2` with the specific package's variant.

```r
# library(...)                # for all others, not for read.csv2
ps::ps_memory_info()
#        rss        vms     shared       text        lib       data      dirty 
#   60686336 2385027072   14942208       4096          0 2280714240          0 
system.time(dat <- read.csv2("quux.csv", colClasses = c("integer", "Date")))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  48.198  13.453  61.665 
ps::ps_memory_info()
#        rss        vms     shared       text        lib       data      dirty 
# 1304268800 3628929024   14942208       4096          0 3524616192          0 
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ int: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ dat: Date, format: "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" "2023-09-13" ...
(1304268800 - 60686336) / 2^20
# [1] 1185.973                # MB
```

**Up front**: these are low-strength benchmarks. Measuring time and memory-consumption on single runs are prone to several other extrinsic/unrelated issues, so take any "small" differences with a grain of salt. It's the larger (order-of-magnitude) differences that should be more noteworthy.

```r
library(readr)
dat <- read_delim("quux.csv", col_types = "iD", delim = ";")
#    user  system elapsed 
#  16.885   0.624   1.583 
(227213312 - 78270464) / 2^20
# [1] 142.043
```

(Note that recent versions of `readr` use `vroom` under the hood.)

```r
library(vroom)
dat <- vroom("quux.csv", col_types = "iD", delim = ";")
#    user  system elapsed 
#   9.374   0.452   0.800 
(511553536 - 80756736) / 2^20
# [1] 410.8398
```

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("quux.csv", colClasses = c("integer", "Date"), sep = ";")
#    user  system elapsed 
#  50.908  13.652  57.492 
(1405636608 - 72237056) / 2^20
# [1] 1271.629

dat <- fread("quux.csv", sep = ";")
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.822   0.132   0.285 
(155389952 - 60440576) / 2^20
# [1] 90.55078
class(dat$dat)
# [1] "IDate" "Date"
```

```r
library(arrow)
dat <- read_delim_arrow("quux.csv", delim = ";")
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.667   0.516   0.300 
(601952256 - 101597148) / 2^20
# [1] 477.1758
```

(For arrow, with larger data one might choose `as_data_frame=FALSE` and then do a sequence of dplyr `mutate`/`filter`/`select`/`summarize`/... on it before `collect`. The list of supported operations is impressive, but it does not take arbitrary/complex R expressions ... but if you can live within what is supported before `collect()`ing the data into memory, it can present huge memory savings.)

All of the calls above returned class `Date` for the second column of the file, none of them required user-code to make that change.

## However ...

The benchmarks paint some different efficiencies:

| func | elapsed | rss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| read.csv2 | 61.665 | 1185.97300 |
| readr::read_delim | 1.583 | 142.04300 |
| vroom::vroom | 0.800 | 410.83980 |
| data.table::fread (colClasses) | 57.492 | 1271.62900 |
| data.table::fread (Idate) | 0.285 | 90.55078 |
| arrow::read_delim_arrow | 0.300 | 477.17580 |

The `read.csv2` and `fread` (with `colClasses=`) are clearly the slowest, suggesting that they are using native R code internally to convert strings to `Date`-class columns. Their respective `rss` numbers support the notion that they pull into R as strings first.

The others suggest not only basic reading speed improvements but also significant memory improvements.

I'll leave it as an exercise (and chore) for the reader to find the use/absence of `as.Date` in each function/package.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether (1) we don't really know which columns are dates, (2) we know the first two columns are dates, (3) the date columns are the ones whose name contains the substring "dat" or (4) the date columns are those columns from `dat1` through `second_dat` including any columns between them we could use one of these:

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- tibble(dat1 = "2000-01-01", second_dat = "2000-01-02", c = 3:5, d = "d4")

can.be.date <- function(x) {
  all(is.character(x) & grepl("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$", x))
}
DF %>% mutate(across(where(can.be.date), as.Date))

DF %>% mutate(across(1:2, as.Date))

DF %>% mutate(across(contains("dat"), as.Date))

DF %>% mutate(across(dat1:second_dat, as.Date))
```

Any of these return

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  dat1       second_dat     c d    
  <date>     <date>     <int> <chr>
1 2000-01-01 2000-01-02     3 d4   
2 2000-01-01 2000-01-02     4 d4   
3 2000-01-01 2000-01-02     5 d4
```